# dynamically reference static assets in HTML

Tags: html, css, template-engine

To reference a css file style.css we write it as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../abc/xyz/css/style.css">
```

Same way for images as

```
<img src="../abc/xyz/img/myimage.png" />
```

For all the static assets the path is hard coded. It will create problem if the directory structure changes.
Is it possible to include assets like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{assetsDirectory}}/css/style.css">
<img src="{{assetsDirectory}}/img/myimage.png" />
```

and somewhere in application I specified the configuration in a config.json file as

```
{
  "assetsDirectory" : "../abc/xyz",
  "anyotherproperty" : "anyotherpropertyvalue"
}
```

**EDIT:**
Think of the above as A project
This project can be used by other B project so I want the config file to be specified by the B project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use “variable interpolation”

```
@base-url: "http://assets.yourdomain.com/abc/xyz";
background-image: url("@{base-url}/image.png");
```

Comment: see the edit above. I cannot hard code any path. This can be used by other project so I want config file to be specified by the project which uses it

Comment: I think using [gd-assets](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gd-assets) may be useful for you